# Using Angular and PouchDB for PWA

Tags: angular, pouchdb

I've taken the [Angular Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/) and am attempting to implement a pouchdb service to serve up the data. I've backed up the original hero service, which provided an array of Heroes with different attributes. I'm now attempting to modify the service to pull documents from pouchdb locally. I've modified the HeroService class, and set up some options in the constructor.

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HEROES} from './mock-heroes';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import {MessageService} from './message.service';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HeroService {
  private isInstantiated: boolean;
  private database: any;
  private listener: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();


  constructor(private messageService:MessageService) { 
    if(!this.isInstantiated) {
      this.database = new PouchDB("http://server:5984/db1");
      this.isInstantiated = true;
  }
}



  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  console.log(this.database.allDocs({include_docs: true}))
    return of(this.database.allDocs({include_docs: true}));
    this.messageService.add("HeroService: fetched heroes");

    };
```

A console.log shows a "ZoneAwarePromise" in the hero.service.ts file at the console.log line , but has the array of data and doc's that I want to show on the screen. Am I taking the right approach to this, using a service to provide the data from PouchDB to an Angular app?

The component that I'm trying to show this data in is the "dashboard.components.ts" file, and here's the new function:

```
getHeroes(): void {
    console.log(this.heroes)
    console.log(this.heroService.getHeroes());
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
    .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
    //console.log(this)

  }
```

Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing out on, arguably, the two coolest benefits of Pouch ... **off-line first** and background **live updates**.

To get the former you should instantiate two databases: one remote and the other [local to the browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-browser) itself. You then set up replication between the two. After the first run, without network connectivity at all, your page will work the same as if online. Writes and reads to the local DB will be instantaneous.  When back online, Pouch will synchronize all local and remote data transparently. [This article](https://subvisual.co/blog/posts/130-how-to-build-offline-web-applications-with-couchdb-and-pouchdb/) might help you get started with that, (although you can ignore the stuff about `Phoenix`; you can connect directly to CouchDB).

If you also use *[live-find](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-live-find)*, on-screen data will update within seconds to show server-side changes to the user, with no further special programming needed from you.

Finally, I suggest you evaluate Couchbase (with the replication gateway) instead of CouchDB, it seems to be a rising star, while CouchDB seems to be falling out of favor.